# Build.Model doesn't provide the right information?

Tags: android, model

I am fairly new to the whole android-development.

I am trying to set a different layout depending on the Modelname.

I am working with the android-eclipse SDK

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final String model = Build.MODEL;

    if(model == "sdk")
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_one);
    } else
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_two);
    }
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), model, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The Toast says that the modelname is "sdk", but the if statement isn't executed, as indeed the else-part is executed.

What could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the '==' operator on the String as it checks to see if the string object is the same, not its content. Use `.equals(String)` instead.

```
if ("sdk".equals(model) {
    ...
}
```